# what is a single word metaphor for fast and cheap

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, metaphors

I need a word or phrase that will describe something as fast and cheap (ie; fast and cheap service)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by fast and cheap? I imagine a speedy inexpensive car.

Comment: I mean fast and cheap as in service

Comment: Thanks for the check-mark, but feel free to remove it and come back in 24 hours to see if anybody else has given you a better answer. Giving the check mark too early may discourage others from answering, and I'm sure there are other reasonable answers to this question.

Comment: Cheap has connotations of shoddiness - is that a meaning that you're trying to capture, or to avoid?

Comment: Why aren't the two together good enough? Are you trying to squeeze in letters onto a headline or store window with minimal space?

Comment: Explaining a little more of the context (example: Is cheap a good thing in this case? If you are advertising a service, "Mc-" is kind of derogatory even if it is the most popular restaurant in the U.S.) would help and also giving a sample sentence would help meet the board's guidance on single word requests,

Comment: I'm trying to say that my company does things cheap and fast in a positive way but i need it to sound better and be shorter (think company name/tagline)

Answer (score 3):

We have the "Mc-" prefix, indicating something done the way the McDonalds fast food company would do it.

It generally implies something that is done quickly and cheaply, but also repetitively.

For example, we call large houses built in subdivisions with very similar appearance as "McMansions".

You could use this prefix productively to talk about "McService".